# Setting position does not work properly in LibVLC on Android

Tags: android, vlc, rtmp

Setting position (rewind) does not work properly while playing RTMP streams (static files, not live stream) in the VLC player.

The problem was discovered when developing an Android application to work with video archive by RTMP. The application uses a LibVLC player (de.mrmaffen: vlc-android-sdk: 1.9.0). To set the position, use the following code:

```
if (length == 0f)
    mMediaPlayer.setTime(position);
else
    mMediaPlayer.setPosition(position / length);
```

If position is right of the current, the player "waiting" until it comes to this position, focusing on the last frame, and can then start / not start playing from the desired position. If position left of the current, it is reset to the current and will continue to play with it.

If you specify a different stream format (eg, http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4), the setting position is working properly. On the PC in the normal media player VLC problem also occurs. In other players the setting position of RTMP streams works fine.

Can you do something about this bug or work around it to begin to setting position in LibVLC?